# Unrolling nested vector at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, template-meta-programming

I m trying to solve the problem of unrolling the a nested vector like this vector<vector<vector..>..>, I want to access the core `int` element. I wrote this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename S>
void print(S);

template<typename T, typename S>
void decode(T container) {
        if(std::is_same<T,S>::value)
                print<S>(container);
        else{
                for(auto i : container){
                        decode<decltype(i), S>(i);
                }
        }
}

template<typename S>
void print(S ele){
        std::cout<<ele<<" ";
}

int main(){
        std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> a = {{{1,2,3},{4,5}}};
        decode<decltype(a), int>(a);

}
```

but it is showing

```
nested_vector_decoder.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void decode(T) [with T = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >; S = int]’:
nested_vector_decoder.cpp:26:28:   required from here
nested_vector_decoder.cpp:11:12: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >’ to ‘int’
   11 |   print<S>(container);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~
      |            |
      |            std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >
nested_vector_decoder.cpp:20:14: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void print(S) [with S = int]’
   20 | void print(S ele){
```

I m not able to understand why I see this error, because I m already checking at compile `container` whether its a `int` or not here `if(std::is_same<T,S>::value)`, can anyone explain me

shouldnt the error message serve as warning message.

AND yes I did saw answers on unrolling nested vector, but I want to know what I m doing wrong, how does things work internally so I could understand it.

Thank You.

Also is this kind of operation possible in runtime in c++?

Comment: You are looking for `if constexpr(std::is_same<T,S>::value)`. Otherwise the condition is not checked at compile time and both branches are generated. https://godbolt.org/z/bshYe5frq

Comment: Please note that `if constexpr` is C++17 or later (I notice that your question is tagged C++11).